# Simple MPAndroidChart use gives app crash

Tags: mpandroidchart

**Dear Developers!**

I'd like to use the MPAndroidChart lib in app. First, for improve my skils I'd like to make a simple chart from this tutorial:

[MPAndroidChart Tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/add-charts-to-your-android-app-using-mpandroidchart--cms-23335)

It is very simple, so it is for me :)

But, my app desn't work. And I don't know why. Can you help me?

1. My XML file:

   ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dip"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="1" >

       <Button
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:backgroundTint="#299ED6"
           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/gas_ico"
           android:text="13,04\nl/100"
           style="@style/spalanie_value"
           android:textAllCaps="false"/>

       <Button
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:backgroundTint="#FF8B00"
           android:drawableLeft="@drawable/car0_ico"
           android:text="1744\nkm"
           style="@style/spalanie_value"
           android:textAllCaps="false"/>
   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dip"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="1" >

       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:background="#DC3C00"
           android:layout_margin="5dp">


           <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
               android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

               <TableRow
                   android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
                   android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end"
                   android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                   android:paddingTop="10dp"
                   android:paddingRight="5dp"
                   android:paddingBottom="10dp">

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tvData"
                       android:text="@string/data"
                       style="@style/naglowki_tabeli"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:layout_width="33dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tvSpalanie"
                       android:text="@string/spalanie"
                       style="@style/naglowki_tabeli"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:layout_width="33dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tvZasieg"
                       android:text="@string/zasieg"
                       style="@style/naglowki_tabeli"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:layout_width="33dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
               </TableRow>

               <TableRow
                   android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                   android:measureWithLargestChild="false"
                   android:padding="5dp"
                   android:showDividers="middle|beginning|end">

                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tvDataData"
                       android:text="2015-03-24\n2015-04-12\n2015-05-17\n2015-06-05"
                       style="@style/dane_tabeli"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:layout_width="33dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                       android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tvSpalanieData"
                       android:text="8,12 l\n12,16 l\n17,20 l\n14,66 l"
                       style="@style/dane_tabeli"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:layout_width="33dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
                   <TextView
                       android:id="@+id/tvZasiegData"
                       android:text="480 km\n405 km\n370 km\n389 km"
                       style="@style/dane_tabeli"
                       android:layout_gravity="center"
                       android:layout_width="33dp"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                       android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
               </TableRow>



           </TableLayout>
       </FrameLayout>


   </LinearLayout>

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="0dip"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_weight="1" >

       <FrameLayout
           android:layout_width="0dip"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:background="#008272"
           android:layout_margin="5dp" >

           <com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart
               android:id="@+id/chart"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent" />


           </FrameLayout>


   </LinearLayout>
   ```

2. My JAVA file:

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
           getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
   mTitle = getTitle();

   // Set up the drawer.
   mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
           R.id.navigation_drawer,
           (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));

   ArrayList entries = new ArrayList();
   entries.add(new BarEntry(4f, 0));
   entries.add(new BarEntry(8f, 1));
   entries.add(new BarEntry(6f, 2));
   entries.add(new BarEntry(12f, 3));
   entries.add(new BarEntry(18f, 4));
   entries.add(new BarEntry(9f, 5));

   BarDataSet mydataset = new BarDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");

   ArrayList labels = new ArrayList();
   labels.add("January");
   labels.add("February");
   labels.add("March");
   labels.add("April");
   labels.add("May");
   labels.add("June");

   BarChart b1;

   b1=(BarChart) findViewById(R.id.chart);

   BarData dane = new BarData(labels,mydataset);

   b1.setData(dane);     }
   ```
3. Result: crash of app and logcat:

> 06-25 10:54:12.418  26699-26699/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
>   06-25 10:54:12.572  26699-26699/com.mkilinski.spalanie D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
>   06-25 10:54:12.573  26699-26699/com.mkilinski.spalanie E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.mkilinski.spalanie, PID: 26699
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mkilinski.spalanie/com.mkilinski.spalanie.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.github.mikephil.charting.charts.BarChart.setData(com.github.mikephil.charting.data.ChartData)' on a null object reference

Comment: I've made some kind of debbuger. Like this:

LineChart lchart = (LineChart) findViewById(R.id.linechart);
        String text = String.valueOf(lchart.getId());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Nothing else. Still the same issue - app crash.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a top-level layout in your .xml file

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if I create a chart dynamically in Java and setContentView(chartName), it runs fine.
But ones getting access to the chart defined in xml, calling 
(xxxChart) findViewById(R.id.my_chart_id); it throws this exception?